# Android SugarORM Tried to save a record, successfull, but it looks like it was stuck in some look

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sugarorm

I'm new to SugarORM, I've tried to save a record.

```
Report report = new Report(SessionManager.getInstance().getUserid(),
                           assessmentContainer.getAssessmentTitle(),
                           getDateTimeNow(), response);
report.save();
```

In the quick guide given by SugarORM, it seemed to include the context, but I didn't know how to include my context, it somehow conflicts with my Report constructor, so I omit it.

Looks like it did successfully, but it seems inefficient. Any idea what's wrong? Take a look at my log below.

```
02-01 14:10:32.736      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ on create
02-01 14:10:33.136      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.136      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.136      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.136      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.136      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.146      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.146      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.146      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.146      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.146      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.146      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.146      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.146      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.146      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.146      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.146      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.146      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.146      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.146      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.146      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.146      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.156      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.156      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.156      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.156      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.156      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.156      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.156      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.156      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.156      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.156      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.156      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.156      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.156      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.156      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.156      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.156      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.156      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.156      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.156      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.156      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.156      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.156      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.166      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.166      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ domain class
02-01 14:10:33.166      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ create table
02-01 14:10:33.166      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs D/Sugar﹕ Fetching properties
02-01 14:10:33.166      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ creating table REPORT
02-01 14:10:33.176      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Sugar﹕ Report saved : 1
02-01 14:10:33.196      903-903/com.usrs.jiarong.musrs I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the first start of sugarorm it has to generate the models for the database. Make sure you specified the DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME  to your package with the needed tables.

Comment: Surely, it disappeared after the first time. I guess it's only the initialization part.

Comment: Yes, only the first time.

Comment: Yes it is working after first time, how to fix for the first time? I am unable to fetch data at first time form 2nd activity, when I restart app it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

edit compile version in your app's build.gradle

`compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.5'`

and in model extend only with  `SugarRecord`

I have fixed using this method.